# SQL select given another query

Tags: sql, sqlite

So I would like to search for the max time in a column:

```
sqlite> SELECT max(strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M',time)) FROM posts WHERE thread_id=123456;
2012-10-02 02:31
```

For each thread_id returned by this query:

```
sqlite> SELECT thread_id FROM threads WHERE out_of_date=0;
111
123
187
...
```

Then I would like to search for all threads whose `last_post` field don't match the `time` field returned by the first query, and set the `out_of_date` field to 1:

```
sqlite> UPDATE threads SET out_of_date=1 WHERE thread_id=123456 AND last_post!='2012-10-02 02:31';
```

Problem is, I'm not too sure how I should go about combining these three separate queries. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below SQL should update the threads table correctly.  It uses a correlated sub-query to combine the 1st and 3rd of your queries.  This can then be combined with your 2nd query by adding it's `WHERE` clause.

```
UPDATE threads T
SET out_of_date = 1
WHERE out_of_date = 0
    AND last_post != (
        SELECT MAX(strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M',time))
        FROM posts
        WHERE thread_id = T.thread_id
    )
;
```

Comment: Excellent! Many thanks! By the way, did you mean to put `strftime` by itself? It seems like that would be asking to select the maximum of the strftime column, which does not exist.

Comment: @wrongusername I tested it with a column I named `strftime` but forgot to change it in the answer!  Thanks for pointing that out.